# I trial make Permission in CreateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to check if user in true editUser before open url and create post,

urls.py", line 13, in 
path('new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='new_post'),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'as_view'

```
def notLoggedUsers(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request,*args,**kwargs):
        if not request.user.profile.editUser:
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return view_func(request,*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapper_func

@notLoggedUsers
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'crud/new_post.html'
    form_class =  PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user 
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: You should not decorate the class, since your decorator decorates a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your decorator has a small mistake, the indentation for `return wrapper_func` is wrong. Next to decorate class based views you should use [`method_decorator` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) and specify the method of the class that should be decorated (Decorate the `dispatch` method if it needs to decorate the complete view):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


def notLoggedUsers(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.profile.editUser:
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func


@method_decorator(notLoggedUsers, name='dispatch')
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'crud/new_post.html'
    form_class =  PostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user 
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* decorate your class-based view with a decorator that *returns a function*, since then that function has no `.as_view` attribute.

Django has some tooling to apply a decorator to a function of the class-based view, we can however also implement a mixin and work with that mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class EditUserPermissionPlugin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        try:
            return self.user.profile.editUser
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            return False

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect('index')
```

Then we can use this for our view:

```
class SomeCreateView(EditUserPermissionPlugin, CreateView):
    # …
```